# List all docker services without using swarm

Tags: docker

What is the docker command (or how) to list all the services running in docker?

I have tried `docker service ps service`

Output: `Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.`

I am not using docker swarm and don't want to. I am looking for an equivalent of `kubectl get services` in docker.

Comment: Do you want to list all running docker containers?

Comment: No, I don't want to list running containers (docker ps) @josephjacobmorris

Comment: docker services are specific to docker swarm 
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service/

Comment: Thank you, I confused the semantics with kubernetes- service instead of network. `docker network ls`  is what I was actually looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this because I did actually want the services (not the container names or networks in the accepted answer);

```bash
➜  xxxx git:(main) ✗ docker service ls
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.
```

Made a short one-liner to list all `com.docker.compose.service` which you'd usually have to get from individually `docker inspect` on each container;

```bash
echo "CONTAINER ID \t NAME \t\t SERVICE" && for container_id in $(docker ps -q); do service=$(docker inspect --format '{{ index .Config.Labels "com.docker.compose.service" }}' $container_id); name=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .Name }}' $container_id | sed 's/\///g'); echo "$container_id \t $name \t $service"; done
```

```
CONTAINER ID       NAME           SERVICE
1a2b3c4d5e6f       example_1      service_1
7g8h9i0j1k2l       example_2      service_2
3m4n5o6p7q8r       example_3      service_3
9s8t7u6v5w4x       example_4      service_4
2y3z4a5b6c7d       example_5      service_5
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting @josephjacobmorris from the comments:

```
docker services are specific to docker swarm
```

This question is due to confusing `networks` and `services` in docker.

Answer: The required command is `docker network ls`